# How to horizontaly flip graphics in paintComponent? java

Tags: java, graphics, rotation, flip

In the `paintComponent` method for `JPanel`, I am drawing an image using `Graphics`, but I need to be horizontally flipped, and the flipping needs to take place in that method. How can I do this?

RoosterB is a child of Rooster, which is a child of JPanel.

```
public class RoosterB extends Rooster
{
    public RoosterB()
    {

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // Red stuff
        g.setColor(new Color(56, 118, 29));
        g.drawLine(6, 0, 11, 0);
        g.drawLine(9, 1, 13, 1);
        g.drawLine(8, 2, 9, 2);
        g.drawLine(12, 2, 13, 2);
        g.drawLine(12, 5, 12, 7);
        g.drawLine(13, 5, 13, 9);
        g.drawLine(14, 4, 14, 8);

        g.drawLine(5, 23, 5, 23);
        g.drawLine(8, 24, 8, 24);

        // Beak
        g.setColor(new Color(241, 194, 50));
        g.drawLine(13, 5, 14, 5);
        g.drawLine(13, 7, 15, 7);

        // Eye
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(10, 3, 10, 4);
        g.setColor(new Color(147,196,125));
        g.drawLine(11, 3, 11, 4);

        // Wing
        g.setColor(new Color(102, 102, 102));
        g.drawLine(0, 12, 0, 13);
        g.drawLine(1, 12, 1, 15);
        g.drawLine(2, 13, 2, 16);
        g.drawLine(3, 13, 9, 13);
        g.drawLine(3, 14, 8, 14);
        g.drawLine(3, 15, 7, 15);
        g.drawLine(7, 12, 8, 12);
        g.drawLine(8, 11, 8, 11);
        g.drawLine(10, 11, 10, 12);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(3, 16, 6, 16);
        g.drawLine(8, 15, 8, 15);
        g.drawLine(9, 14, 9, 14);
        g.drawLine(10, 13, 10, 13);

        // Feet
        g.setColor(new Color(147,196,125));
        g.drawLine(5, 24, 5, 25);
        g.drawLine(8, 25, 8, 25);
        g.setColor(new Color(56, 118, 29));
        g.drawLine(4, 26, 6, 26);
        g.drawLine(5, 27, 5, 27);
        g.drawLine(8, 26, 8, 28);
        g.drawLine(7, 27, 9, 27);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post a [MCVE] with the `paintComponent` you have ?

Comment: Flip the image using gimp or a similar program and then load one or the other.

Comment: Is that more helpful @c0der ?

Comment: @Lowenstein, how is it complete? We can't compile or execute the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is closer to a MCVE :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class APanel extends JPanel{

    private Line2D line;

    APanel(){

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,400));
        line = new Line2D.Double(50,100, 500,250);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.draw(line);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new APanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Isn't it? 
Using it simplifies the question and the answer :

```
public class APanel extends JPanel{

    double x1 = 50, y1 = 100, x2 = 500, y2 = 250; //line ends
    double fx1, fx2, fy1, fy2; // fliped line ends
    boolean flip = false;

    APanel(){
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,400));
        JButton flipBtn = new JButton("Flip");
        flipBtn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,30));
        flipBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                flip = ! flip;
                repaint();
            }
        });
        add(flipBtn);
        calculteFlipedLine();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);

        if(flip) {
            g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(x1, y1, x2, y2));
        } else {
            g2d.draw(new Line2D.Double(fx1, fy1, fx2, fy2));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new APanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void calculteFlipedLine() {
        //the calculation here is for simplified
        //horizontal flip. It may vary according to how you
        //define flip
        fx1 = x2; fy1 = y1;
        fx2 = x1; fy2 = y2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a horizontal flip, `left <-> right`, you're modifying the x-coordinates.  The general way is

```
x_new = 2 * x_axis - x_old
```

Here `x_axis` is the x-coordinate that the "flip" should be "around."  For example, if you want to draw two mirror images facing each other, pick an `x_axis` entirely to the left or right and draw twice: once flipped and once not.

To make this happen in Java, you should put all your coordinates in an array. This is called a *display list*.  Then draw them with a loop:

```
static struct MyLine {
  int x0, y0, x1, y1;
  Color color;
  MyLine(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, Color color) {
    this.x0 = x0; this.y0 = y0; this.x1 = x1; this.y1 = y1;
    this.color = color;
  }
}

static final Color MY_RED = new Color(56, 118, 29);
static final Color MY_BEAK_COLOR = ...

static final MyLine [] displayList = {
  new MyLine(6, 0, 11, 0, MY_RED);
  ...
};
```

Now in `paintComponent`, render with or without the flip:

```
...
if (flipped) {
  int o = 2 * x_axis;
  for (MyLine line : displayList) {
    g.setColor(line.color);
    g.drawLine(o - line.x0, line.y0, o - line.x1, line.y1);
  }
} else {
  for (MyLine line : displayList) {
    g.setColor(line.color);
    g.drawLine(line.x0, line.y0, line.x1, line.y1);
  }
}
```

When `flip` is true, you'll get the flipped image, else normal. If you want both, then remove the `if`.  One advantage of display lists is that you can draw image components as many times as you like in different versions.